# using the right library with scandit in PhoneGap Build app

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need help in using the right library in my PhoneGap BUILD application. I found Scandit, but I need a guide because I use build.phonegap.com to build my app. So which files should I include in the www project folder? Please also recommend me a "how to start guide".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for your specific implementation, but phonegap build now offers a barcode scanner plugin.

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins

I have built the default project and it's very easy to setup and use.

Here is the READ.ME for the project:

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I work for Scandit. You can access the "how to" guide for getting started with our PhoneGap plugin for iOS or Android here:

http://www.scandit.com/support/documentation/

Let us know if you need any other info!